# CombGuid differents in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a CombGuid with my own seed, and I need that code be generated equals both in C# and SQL Server.

I'm following the idea of CombGuid generation as stated in this site:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862&seqNum=7

I'm also borrowing C# code from:
https://github.com/richardtallent/RT.Comb

The problem I can't make the last group of the Guids be generated equal in both languages. In SQL Server I know it's working, because I can reverse the Guid to Bigint again.

But in C#, when I try reverse it, the value is returned lower than the original.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

**C#**:

```
        //create a Guid and convert it to byte
        var gbytes = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();

        //create the last part of a Guid with a big seed
        var ms = 281474967000000 +  Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(2018,2,21)).TotalMinutes / 10.0);
        var msBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ms);
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(msBytes);

        //copy bytes for later use
        var byteLen = 6;
        var dbytes = new byte[byteLen];
        var index = msBytes.GetUpperBound(0) + 1 - byteLen;
        Array.Copy(msBytes, index, dbytes, 0, byteLen);

        //replace the last part of the guid with my seed
        Array.Copy(dbytes, 0, gbytes, 10, 6);
        var guid = new Guid(gbytes); 
        //results: 6e07bc10-20d6-4cee-aefe-**ffffed7a8ec0**
```

**T-SQL** (SQL Server):

```
--this is how I generate the Guid part          
    SELECT
        CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(10)) + 
        CAST(cast((floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2018-02-21', getdate())/10) + 281474967000000) as bigint) as BINARY(6)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
        --results: 2E2FC4CC-CA45-4C6B-81D2-**FFFFFF6BD45D**

--this is how I check its working
select format(convert(bigint, convert(binary(6), '0x' + 'FFFFFF6BD45D', 1)), '#,0')
```

**Notes**:

In C#, it generated:

```
6e07bc10-20d6-4cee-aefe-ffffed7a8ec0
```

In T-SQL, it generated:

```
2E2FC4CC-CA45-4C6B-81D2-FFFFFF6BD45D
```

Note the last group of the guids only. They would be the same as I'm changing it only at next 10 minutes.

In T-SQL, I can reverse the "FFFFFF6BD45D" back to BigInt with no problems.
In C#, the reversed number is a lower value.

I think that the problem should be in the byte[6] (the size?), but I can't understand why in SQL it works fine and in C# not.

Comment: SQL you are using BIGINT while in c# you are not declaring variables so you are loosing MSB,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is `Math.Floor` return type is `double` in your case, so type of `ms` is `double`. Floating point numbers are represented differently in memory, so  `BitConverter.GetBytes(double)` produces not the same result as `BitConverter.GetBytes(long)`, even if values are the same. So to fix, cast the result to `long`, just as you do in your SQL query (with `as bigint`):

```
var ms = 281474967000000 + (long)Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(2018, 2, 21)).TotalMinutes / 10);
```